# Is this a translation of 逍遥游？

Tags: translation

I think [this](http://www.sacred-texts.com/tao/mcm/mcm05.htm#fr_9) is from [逍遥游](http://baike.baidu.com/view/2788118.htm)， but I'm not sure.  I just can't locate the following sentence.

> Thus, the wise man looks into space, and does not regard the small as
>   too little, nor the great as too much; for he knows that there is no
>   limit to dimension.

Comment: What makes you think it's in that sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's reallys cited from 《庄子》,but not from the chapter of 《逍遥游》. It's from the chapter of 《秋水》. The orginal words for your citation are:

> 是故大知观于远近，故小而不寡，大而不多，知量无穷。
>
> 是故大知觀於遠近，故小而不寡，大而不多，知量無窮。

Comment: Curious... what does 故 mean in this context? I'm having trouble parsing the sentence.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete In classical Chinese, a common pattern of arriving at a conlcusion is XXXX, 是故XXXX，XXX...，故XXX(optional). In this case, 是故 and 故 means "so, therefore".